# Last value of the array 'disapears'

Tags: c++, arrays

So, i am currently doing a project. And while debuging i noticed that sometimes, a variable from the array changes value without me changing it. 
The array is created to hold some values from tree structure.

```
int* tablica_synow1;
tablica_synow1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * number_of_sons(wskaznik_wierzcholki[zmienna1][i]));

//cout << "Initializing values to tablica_synow1" << endl;
for (int k = 0; k < ilu_synow(wskaznik_wierzcholki[zmienna2][j]); k++) {
    if (k == 0)
        tmp = wskaznik_wierzcholki[zmienna2][j]->son;
    tablica_synow1[k] = tmp->key;
    //cout << "tablica_synow1 [" << k << "]" << tablica_synow1[k] << endl;
    tmp = tmp->brother;
}
//cout <<"end of initialization"<< endl;
```

after this I do some other things in my code that don't involde tablica_synow1
and then when i want to use it

```
for (int m = 0; m < ilu_synow(wskaznik_wierzcholki[zmienna2][j]); m++) {
    int x = tablica_synow1[m];
    cout << "tablica synow1 [" << m << "]" << tablica_synow1[m] << endl;
    int y = i;
    int a;
    if (x > 0)
        a = tablica2[y][zwroc_indeks(wartosci_tab[zmienna2], x)];
    else
        a = tablica4[y][x * (-1)];

    if (a > najwieksza)
        najwieksza = a;
}
```

the last element goes from 2 to -123781237 and it breaks my code
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVR24.png)

Comment: You probably go beyond the array bounds. Hard to say without [mcve].

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program?  Why not use `std::vector<int>`?  Second, you allocate `number_of_sons(wskaznik_wierzcholki[zmienna1][i])` integers, but then you loop with `k` using a different value as the limit.  How do you know that `k` is always less than `number_of_sons(wskaznik_wierzcholki[zmienna1][i]`?